# Regular Expressions using Python

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a function using regular expressions for emails. I think I write the pattern correctly, however, I couldn't find out why example 2 **'what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com'** failed to be detected while example 1 worked successfully?

```
def parse_email(s):
    try:
        pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-zA-Z])([\w.-_+]+)@([\w.-]+)([a-zA-Z])\b')
        matches = pattern.finditer(s)
        for match in matches:
            print(match.group(0))
            return (match.group(1)+match.group(2), match.group(3)+match.group(4))
    except AttributeError:
        #print('here')
        raise ValueError


print(parse_email('JKRowling@Huge-Books.org'))
print(parse_email('what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com'))
```

Results:

```
JKRowling@Huge-Books.org
('JKRowling', 'Huge-Books.org')

much@gmail.com
('much', 'gmail.com')
```

Comment: `-` has special meaning inside `[]` in a regexp, it's used to specify a range of characters, like `a-z`. What do you think `.-_` matches?

Answer (score 1):

From [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) docs:

> Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal digit. **If - is escaped (e.g. [a-z]) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. [-a] or [a-]), it will match a literal '-'.** [emphasis added]

It looks like you are trying to match a literal `-`, so place it as the first character of the range, e.g. `[-xxx]`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-zA-Z])([-\w._+]+)@([-\w.]+)([a-zA-Z])\b')
```

Test:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = r"\b([a-zA-Z])([-\w._+]+)@([-\w.]+)([a-zA-Z])\b"
>>> old_pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-zA-Z])([\w.-_+]+)@([\w.-]+)([a-zA-Z])\b')
>>> new_pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-zA-Z])([-\w._+]+)@([-\w.]+)([a-zA-Z])\b')
>>> old_pattern.search('what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com')
<re.Match object; span=(21, 35), match='much@gmail.com'>
>>> new_pattern.search('what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 35), match='what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com'>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to put it at the front of the group and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of regular expressions, where the tiniest of changes can result in totally unexpected outcomes.

**To start, let's analyze the regex pattern you have:**

> `r'\b([a-zA-Z])([\w.-_+]+)@([\w.-]+)([a-zA-Z])\b'`

- `\b` is a correct choice, since you want items which are there own word. Be careful though, since this won't include the beginning or end of a string.
- `([a-zA-Z])` if your first capture group. You can replace with the simpler `([A-z])`
- `([\w.-_+]+)` is your second capture group. It will capture:

  - `\w` any word character (redundant)
  - `.` will not necessarily capture the period character, instead, is capturing "any" character
  - `-` will not capture the dash character, instead, will capture a range of characters
  - `_` will indeed capture underscore characters – but in this case, it's being referenced as the end of a range
  - `+` will not capture plus characters, rather, will get "1 or more" characters from a group or range.

*... I'll stop here, since the rest is more or less similar...*

**You'll want to replace your regex with the following:**

> `r'\b([A-z0-9\-\+]+@[A-z\-\+]+\.[A-z]{3})\b'`

- There is only one capture group, since we want entire email addresses.
- Email addresses (here) are allowed to contain:

  - Before the at symbol: `[A-z0-9\-\+]+` all alpha-numeric characters as well as `'-'` and `'+'` characters (as denoted by the escaped characters `\-` and `\+`
  - Following the at symbol, a domain name `[A-z\-\+]` with alpha characters and escaped chars
  - Followed by a domain extension `\.[A-z]{3}` Ex: `.org`

Next, you can refactor your code to the following:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\b([A-z0-9\-\+]+@[A-z\-\+]+\.[A-z]{3})\b')
match = pattern.search(s)

if match:
   email = match.group()
else:
   email = None
```

Comment: Thank you for carefully analyzing my code. I wonder why you think \w is redundant?

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[A-z]+` @CodingLife